# Graph data in pairs as segments

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, lattice

I am attempting to plot pairs of points because this is the format in which they occur. This data describes commercial parts (electronic components) whose behavior is described as ranging between two frequencies. This is a small example of a data set:

```
freq1  freq2  gain  
2.0    6.0    43
6.0   18.0    40
8.5   10.5    50 
8.5    9.3    52
```

Because the data is presented over a range of frequencies, **I want to display this as a line joining the two points**. For example, the first line describes two points: (2, 43) and (6, 43).

Anoather possibility is to calculate the center frequency, locate the point there and calculate a width to **the image I draw at each point so that it ranges from `freq1` and `freq2`**. This raises so many questions I can't begin to write the code.

So, my question is: wow can I plot each `gain` values against lines joining `freq1` and `freq2` (preferably using ggplot2)?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: You might need to clarify what type of plot you're looking for.  The way it reads is a little vague as to what your output should look like.

Comment: His question is there, it's just a bit convoluted.

Comment: I am used to a standard plot where I would plot individual points. Instead, the data is presented over a range of frequencies. The first line provides two points, (2.0, 43) and (6.0, 43). In this case, I would need to draw a horizontal line between those two points, and do the same for each pair of points I have been given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what it's worth, here's an idea with `ggplot2`. I'll let you build anything over it, although it has more or less everything.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=freq1, y=gain)) + 
      geom_segment(aes(xend=freq2, yend=gain, colour=factor(1:4)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Just a guess, `latticeExtra` has an interesting `segplot` (it is an extended dotplot)

[image]

Reading some data:

```
  dat <- read.table(text ='freq1  freq2  gain  
2.0    6.0    43.
6.0   18.0    40.
8.5   10.5    50. 
8.5    9.3    52.',head=T)

dat$compo <- paste('compo',1:nrow(dat),sep='')
library(latticeExtra)
segplot(reorder(factor(compo), gain)~freq1+freq2,
        data=dat,draw.bands=FALSE,centers=gain,
        segments.fun = panel.arrows,ends = "both", 
        angle = 90, length = 1, scales=list(y=list(cex=1.5)),
        unit = "mm",
        main = ' Range frequencies'  ,sub= 'electronic components', 
        ## a serious theme here :)
        par.settings = theEconomist.theme(with.bg = TRUE))
```

**EDIT** add some pictures

```
library(png)

ll <- list.files(path=path_picts,patt='compo[0-9].*',full.names=T)
imgs <- lapply(ll,readPNG)
#ll <- gsub('.*(compo[0-9]).png','\\1',ll)
#names(imgs) <- ll
dat$compo <- paste('compo',1:nrow(dat),sep='')
segplot(factor(compo)~freq1+freq2,
        data=dat,draw.bands=FALSE,centers=gain,
        segments.fun = panel.arrows,ends = "both", 
        angle = 90, length = 1, scales=list(y=list(cex=1.5)),
        unit = "mm",
        main = ' Range frequencies'  ,sub= 'electronic components',
        par.settings = ggplot2like(),axis = axis.grid,

        panel = function(x,y,...){
            panel.segplot(x,y,...)
            browser()
            lapply(seq_along(ll),function(img){
                 x1 <- x[img];y1 <- y[img];
                  grid.raster(image=imgs[[img]],x=(x1+y1)*0.5,y=img,width=y1-x1, height=0.5,interpolate=F,
                        default.units = 'native')})

        })
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Here is the answer to your question

```
> dat
  freq1 freq2 gain
1   2.0   6.0   43
2   6.0  18.0   40
3   8.5  10.5   50
4   8.5   9.3   52

> attach(dat)

#Don't actually need to calculate the midpoint but since you suggested it
#that's the way I did it
midpoint = (freq1+freq2)/2
plot(midpoint,gain,xlim=c(min(freq1),max(freq2)),col="white",xlab="")

points(freq1,gain,col=1:length(gain),pch=19)
points(freq2,gain,col=1:length(gain),pch=19)

for(i in 1:length(gain)){
    lines(c(freq1[i],freq2[i]),c(gain[i],gain[i]),col=i)
}
```

[image]

Comment: The `segments` function seems like a better option than the for loop with `lines`.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this in ggplot2?

Comment: @Greg, Thanks for pointing that out.  I had never heard of the segments function, but now that I have, I will certainly start using it!

Comment: @Paul, I never use ggplot2 but I am sure there is.

Comment: @PaulM why do you want ggplot2? just for ggplot2 theme?

Comment: If this data is useful, I would be laying it down on top of an existing ggplot2 display. There is already a high level of complexity to the plot, and I don't want to start over with another approach.

Comment: @PaulM You should mention this in your question. because  if we can guess That you want a segments intervals plots , we can't guess you have a complex plot.

Comment: My apologies. I will try to do a better description next time.